# 404 Server error found when search URL

Tags: permissions, web-hosting

[image]

I Create a folder in sub-domain directory but when I search a url i got a error. I attached image below.

And one more thing i share with you recently i upgrade my hosting shared hosting to dedicate hosting. Please help me i don't know what i do because i would not create a website for my client.(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: your webserver is running?

Comment: yes webserver is running properly but i create new folder they don't work properly

Comment: and demo.madhya.agency/ other sub-folder working properly because i create this folder or client website before hosting upgrade .